# Mongoose set function using with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello i am trying to set string value to my column of model.
The string value comes with promise but it can't be returned.

```
    photoUrl: {
    type: String,
    set: setImage,
    default: ""
},
```

this is my model  column

```
function setImage(base64) {
    uploadImage('users', base64).then(
        (publishUri) => {
            return publishUri
        }, 
        (err) => {
            return ''
        }
    )
}
```

this is my set function

```
module.exports = {
    uploadImage: function(storageURI, base64) {
        return new Promise((res,rej) => {
            const storagePathURI = keys.devStorageURI + storageURI + '/';
            const uid = uuidv4();
            createFolder(storagePathURI, uid).then((fileUri, err) => {
                if (err) return rej(err)
                saveImage(fileUri, base64, storageURI, uid).then((publishStorageUri, err) => {
                    console.log(publishStorageUri)
                    console.log(err)
                    if (err) return rej(err)
                    return res(publishStorageUri)
                })
            })  
        })
    }
}

function createFolder(storagePathURI, uuid) {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        mkdirp(storagePathURI, (err) => {
            if (err) return rej(err)
            const fileUri = storagePathURI + uuid + '.png';
            return res(fileUri);
        })
    })
}

function saveImage(fileUri, base64, storageURI, uuid) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        var base64Data = base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");  
            fs.writeFile(fileUri, base64Data, 'base64', (err) => {
                if (err) return rej(err)
                return keys.prodPublishStorageURI + storageURI + '/'  + uuid + '.png';
            })
    })
}
```

and this is my storage helper class

class is working great and value return correctly 
but just my problem is i cant set the value that returned to my photoUrl column
how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing promise with callback. I made some changes to the code:

```
module.exports = {
  uploadImage: function (storageURI, base64) {
      const storagePathURI = keys.devStorageURI + storageURI + '/';
      const uid = uuidv4();
      //return a promise, createFolder returns a promise
      return createFolder(storagePathURI, uid)
      .then(
        fileUri =>
          //return result of saveImage (is a promise)
          saveImage(fileUri, base64, storageURI, uid)
      ).then(
        //in a promise chain you can return a value or promise of value
        //  if you return a value the next then is called with that value
        //  if you return a promise of value (like returning result of saveImage)
        //  the next then is called with the result of that promise
        publishStorageUri => {
          console.log("publish storage uri:",publishStorageUri);
          return publishStorageUri;
        }
      ).catch(
        err=>{
          console.warn("something went wrong:",err);
          //let code calling uploadImage know something went wrong
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }
      )
  }
}

const createFolder = (storagePathURI, uuid) =>
  new Promise(
    (res, rej) =>
      mkdirp(
        storagePathURI,
        (err) =>
          (err) 
            ? rej(err)
            : storagePathURI + uuid + '.png'
    )
  );

const saveImage = (fileUri, base64, storageURI, uuid) =>
  new Promise(
    (res, rej) =>
      fs.writeFile(
        fileUri,
        base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ""),
        'base64',
        (err) =>
          (err)
            ? rej(err)
            : keys.prodPublishStorageURI + storageURI + '/' + uuid + '.png'
      )
    );
```

Depending how badly you screwed up `mkdirp` this may or may not work.

**update**

There are no asynchronous setters or getters in Mongoose schema, you can add an instance method on the schema:

```
yourSchema.methods.setPhotoUrl = function () {
  return setImage()
  .then(
    publishUri=>
      this.setPhotoUrl=publishUri
  ).then(
    ()=>this//return this
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much
But my problem is still continue

in set function i can not return the publishStorageUri because it comes with promise